# Laravel returns unauthenticated but keeps running request

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have an API that I can export multiple data with relations, but I just buy a new server, and in this server when I make request with a big json it reachs the route file twice and returns Unauthenticated (it should'nt cause its just one request and I don't make any redirects), with a smaller json it doesn't happens.

But even return unauthenticated I can see in my logs that the request keeps runing

[image]

That is my server configs

```
memory_limit = 200M
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
post_max_size = 200M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
default_socket_timeout = 600
max_user_connections = 1000
```

**UPDATE**

weird thing, when I add an `dump('test')` in some part of my controller, it doesn't return the unauthenticated exception and at the final of the request returns the json of success

Comment: What is your json file size

Comment: @Shibon is a string of 21760 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending any data in the request header ?
add to root .htaccess hope this will work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Only the `Content-Type` with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the CSRF is disabled

Comment: unfortunately I already has it on my htaccess inside public folder, I'm using ssl, it changes samething?